# How to insert user input values from TextBox and ComboBox to DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to insert user input values from TextBox and ComboBox to DataGrid?

When we click the Save button I have done this

In my Xmal:

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,12,12">
            <DataGrid Name="customerDataGrid" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" Margin="34,56,237,73" AlternatingRowBackground="{x:Null}" MinRowHeight="10"></DataGrid>
            <TextBlock Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,110,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Equipment" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,137,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="ID" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,163,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Start Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,187,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="End Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,211,0,0" Name="textBlock5" Text="Requsted By" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,233,0,0" Name="textBlock6" Text="Purpose" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="568,56,0,0" Name="textBlock7" Text="ADD Maintainence Shedule" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="617,110,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="LA"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="CVT"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Isolator"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="WT"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="ICT"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="CT"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="PT"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="E/S"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="CB"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="BUS" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="CAP" />
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="618,133,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="29A/00"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="29B/00"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="30A/03"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="45B/50"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="39A/00"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="59A/00"/>
                            </ComboBox>
            <DatePicker Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="618,157,0,0" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" />
            <DatePicker Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="618,0,0,251" Name="datePicker2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="99" />
            <TextBox Height="21" Margin="618,208,51,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="21" Margin="618,231,51,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="612,270,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
            <TextBlock Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="554,85,0,0" Name="textBlock8" Text="BAY" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="617,85,0,0" Name="comboBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kolhapur 1" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kolhapur 2" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kolhapur 3" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kolhapur 4" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Vita 1" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Vita 2" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Karad 1" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Karad 2" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Miraj" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Pophali" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Pedambe" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Peth" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Koyana 1" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Koyana 2" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lonikand" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lamboti" />
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
```

And in my Xmal.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            customerDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData();
        }
    public List<Customer> LoadCollectionData()
        {
            List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>();

    customer.Add(new Customer()
            {
                Bay = "Kolhapur 1",
                Euqipment = "JKL",
                ID = "JKL",
                Startmdy = new Calendar(),
                Endmdy = new Calendar(),
                Purpose = "Oiling.", 
                Requestedby = "Ashish.",
            });
            return customer;
        }
    }
public class Customer 
    {
        public string  Bay { get; set; }
        public string Euqipment { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public Calendar Startmdy { get; set; }
        public Calendar Endmdy { get; set; }
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
        public string Requestedby { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have tried many ways but they are not working. Any help or some reference will do.

Comment: your have not given complete code, there is no save button's click event and xaml is also not complete

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection to represent each row of the datagrid. You will be working with the Context...(client side)

Loop through the records in the data grid and find the text box of each row - pick up that value and add to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML is close.  It's missing the data bindings that connect the controls in your `DataGrid` to the objects in the `ItemsSource`.

First, don't set the `ItemsSource` on the `DataGrid`.  Set its `DataContext` to the customer list instead.  Then set the `ItemsSource` via binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...
```

For your text boxes, bind the `Text` property to the property in the item:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

For your combo boxes, bind the `SelectedValue` property to the property in the item:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```